# Is it possible to use nested query strings with react router? If so, how would I set it up?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have one Route for my search results:

```
<Route exact path="/search/:queryString" render={RenderSearchResults} />
```

And a second for my post result:

```
<Route 
    exact 
    path="/search/:queryString/post/:slug" 
    render={getPost} 
/>
```

However, when I try to route here, the url is generated correctly, however it am not routed.  When I look into the location prop, I see that the /post/:slug is appended to the search attribute.  Why is this, and what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Does `getPost` return a Component?

2. I suppose, probably this is an order issue.
`Route` with path `"/search/:queryString/post/:slug"` should be rendered before `Route` with `"/search/:queryString"`. More details can found in this example  https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components/route-matchers.

Comment: Yes, getPost renders a post component which is a blog post.  Thanks for the reference!  Regardless if `"/search/:queryString/post/:slug"` is rendered before or after `"/search/:queryString"` it includes `/post/:slug` as part of the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define your routes different way like wrap up with **`<BrowserRoute>`**

```
return (
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/search/:queryString" component={RenderSearchResults} />
         <Route exact path="/search/:queryString/post/:slug" component={getPost} />
      </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
)
```

And try with **`react-router-dom`** instead of **`react-router`**.

**`react-router-dom`** use **`react-router`** as core

Finally import the required stuff

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom"
```

Hope it will work